# RN - How to create components and put other components in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a custom component and put other components like  or  inside this component but it doesn't seem to be working (nothing shows up). Could someone be kind enough to provide an answer or perhaps correct my understanding where it's gone wrong?

For example, if I have a `Home` page and inside there's a `Card` component where within there's `Text` and `View` components.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, View} from 'react-native'

const CoolCard = ({props}) => {
    return(
        <View>
            {props}
        </View>
    )
}

const Home = () => {
    return(
        <View>
            <CoolCard>
                <Text>This is a cool card!</Text>
            </CoolCard>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Home
```

This doesn't work but if I do

```
const Home = () => {
    return(
        <View>
            <CoolCard props = {
                <Text>This is a cool card!</Text>
            }/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

this works, which I understand. Is there a way for me to write the first example to make it work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use props.children in CoolCars to display thing in first example. In second one you can pass the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the 'children' prop to get the children

```
const CoolCard = ({children}) => {
    return(
        <View>
            {children}
        </View>
    )
}

const Home = () => {
    return(
        <View>
            <CoolCard>
                <Text>This is a cool card!</Text>
            </CoolCard>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to "wrap" a component inside another you can use props.children this is how it looks in a react functional component :

Wrapper component:

```
const WrapComponent = ({children}) => (
   <Text>
     {children}
   </Text>
)
```

Then you can wrap it around any valid JSX:

```
<WrapComponent> {/* put stuff here */} </WrapComponent>
```

You can find more in the official [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx)